# Rails ignores constants in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Is there a trick required to make Rails recognize constants in a SQL select statement?  For example, the following SQL statement is valid:

```
SELECT id, name, 1 AS constant FROM table_name
```

And I would expect the results to have three columns returned:  `id`, `name` and `constant`.   The value in the `constant` column would always be 1.

However, in Rails if I try to do the same thing the constant column gets dropped using `Model.find_by_sql`:

```
TableName.find_by_sql("SELECT id, name, 1 AS constant FROM table_name")
```

or

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id, name, 1 AS constant FROM table_name")
```

Is this is a bug or a known limitation in Rails 4.0 or if there is another way to do this that I'm not trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think your `constant` isn't there? From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql):

> **find_by_sql(sql, binds = [])**
>   [...]
>   If you call a complicated SQL query which spans multiple tables the *columns specified by the SELECT will be attributes of the model, whether or not they are columns of the corresponding table.*

Emphasis mine. So if you say this:

```
a = TableName.find_by_sql("SELECT id, name, 1 AS constant FROM table_name")
```

then you can say `a.first.constant` and get something back. Note that the usual `inspect` output that you're probably looking at in the console won't include `constant` as AR's `inspect` only knows about table columns; you'll see things like this in the console:

```
[#<TableName id: 6, name: "Pancakes">, ...]
```

but the objects will respond to `constant` calls with `'1'`s; yes, they'll probably be strings, you'll have to sort out the type conversions yourself.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply.  I wasn't explicitly looking for the constant in the results so I didn't know it was there.