# Rails model method returning wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

In the Rails console I am attempting to call a method in my model that returns the sum of the quantity of a user's orders.

The method is:

```
def self.user_total(current_user)
  quantity = UserOrder.select("sum(quantity)").where(user_id: current_user)
  quantity
end
```

If I run `Order.user_total(1)` in rails console it returns:
`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserOrder id: nil>]>`

However, the SQL generated is correct:

```
SELECT  sum(quantity) FROM "user_orders" 
WHERE "user_orders"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2 
[["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

And if I run the SQL in dbconsole, it returns the correct sum:

```
SELECT  sum(quantity) FROM user_orders 
WHERE user_orders.user_id = 1;

=> 115
```

It will also return `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserOrder id: nil>]>` if I remove the where constraint.

In rails console if I just generate simple SQL query to find all of the quantities, it returns

```
irb(main):005:0> UserOrder.select("quantity")
  UserOrder Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "user_orders"."quantity" FROM "user_orders" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 1>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 1>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 1>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 1>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 1>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 8>
, #<UserOrder id: nil, quantity: 102>
]>
```

So I can kind of see where `UserOrder id: nil` is coming from, but at the same time why would it return that "column" (for lack of a better word) instead of just the quantities or sum of quantity in the other examples?

Comment: `#inspect` (which produces that `#<UserOrder...` stuff) only tells you thinks that the model knows about, anything else in the query will have an accessor method created as needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351188/479863, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270375/479863, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131675/479863, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17714928/479863, ...

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method for querying the sum:

```
UserOrder.where(user_id: current_user).sum(:quantity)
```

As a style point, I'd say that naming the argument `current_user` doesn't make sense in the model layer because it shouldn't care who the user is that's being queried, be it the "current" logged in user or some other user.

Comment: Ah, that worked! Thank you! Also, noted about the naming convention. So was the way I was going at it wrong? Obviously I was getting the incorrect value, but the logic seemed reasonable at least to pull the quantity

Comment: @Chris Peters a bigger reason to rename the argument `current_user` can be that it is not representing any user at all, but only an "id". So, it could be called `user_id`. :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Good point. It's been a while since I've worked on a Rails app, but it's possible that the argument could contain a model object, and ActiveRecord would grab the `id` from that when building the query. But if all it is is an ID, then certainly name it `user_id`.